# How to make a strip in a response in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, backend

I'm struggling to make up something, and it's that when push notifications arrives to the device, if the title defined by the users has a blank space at the end, the blank space appears in the push notif. It looks very ugyly and I've been trying to get it. I know that I can do it with an rstrip, but not sure how or where. Can anybody please help me? Cheers!

Here is one of the methods:

```
 def self.sell_alert(user, amount, poi_picture)
    return if user.device_token.nil?
    create_params = {
      date: DateTime.now,
      title: "Your content has been sold!",
      message: "\"#{poi_picture.title #Here lies the problem#}\" was sold for $#{sprintf('%.2f',amount)} and your account has been credited. Cheers!",
      poi_picture_id: poi_picture.id,
      notification_type: :payment
    }
    create_and_send_notification(create_params, user.id, SellAlertWorker)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-strip)

> Returns a copy of the receiver with leading and trailing whitespace
> removed.
>
> Whitespace is defined as any of the following characters: null,
> horizontal tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return,
> space.

```
 def self.sell_alert(user, amount, poi_picture)
    return if user.device_token.nil?
    create_params = {
      date: DateTime.now,
      title: "Your content has been sold!",
      message: "\"#{poi_picture.title.strip}\" was sold for $#{sprintf('%.2f',amount)} and your account has been credited. Cheers!",
      poi_picture_id: poi_picture.id,
      notification_type: :payment
    }
    create_and_send_notification(create_params, user.id, SellAlertWorker)
  end
```

If you just want to remove trailing whitespace then use [`String#rstrip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-rstrip) instead.

ActiveSupport also has the [`squish`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish) method which replaces consecutive whitespace groups into one space as well as stripping the string.

I would probally handle this in the setter though instead to solve the issue at its root instead of repeating the same steps whereever you're outputting the title:

```
class PoiPicture < ApplicationRecord
  def title=(str)
    super(str.squish)
  end
end
```

Comment: I applied what you said, and it worked really well. But It still throwing the same error in several places, so I used finally StripAttributes Gem to work it out and now we're ok about that. So, cheers man, thanks a lot!